# changing the template of Primeng Paginator

Tags: angular, inheritance, primeng

I use `primeng` components in my projects. but I want to make some changes in the template of the `paginator` component. I made a new component that extends `paginator`component of `primeng` and I add the new template in `@Component`.
but some other `primeng` components use `paginator` component for their pagination like `dataview`. is there a way that those components can use this new extended version component ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to only change the styling of the paginator?

Comment: yes I want to change the template of paginator.
although I should do some changes for other components like filter methods in dataview , etc...

Answer (score 0):

**When you want to change all primeng components styling**, you can change the primeng css theme imported to your project.

You can change primeng template by changing the imported css in angular.json.
Look for angular.json file, in styles, change the primeng theme css (it should look like this):

```
"styles": [
     ...
     "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
     ...
]
```

Change the - node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/**nova-light**/theme.css - or whatever theme you're using, to a different theme folder name.

**When you want to change a specific component to your needs**, you can add css code to override the default styling of primeng css.

Primeng gives you the classes to override in order to style their component as you need.
For example look at [primeng - dropdown docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/dropdown), you can find a section named 'Styling', showing all of the related css classes to overide in order to style the component as you need it.

I've made a [sample project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-the-template-of-primeng-paginator) where you can see that I've changed the dropdown's icon.

Comment: by template I mean the structure, not the styles. for example I want to change the icons and they are in the template code of primeng paginator.

Comment: I've edit my answer to explain how you're doing that.

Comment: Totally irrelevant answer. He's talking about Angular templates and you're talking about CSS styles.